# How do you make an image fullscreen on image click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, phonegap-build

I have a table with images in it and I am trying to make it so when you click on an image, it then makes that image fullscreen, and you can then click on the fullscreen image and its back to the image table.

I am using phonegap so all of this will be on mobile using html, javascript, css and such. Is there anyway to this without having to link to another page?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: There are many ways of doing this, it is typically called a "lightbox". Many existing solutions do this. Are you using any HTML/CSS frameworks?

Comment: @alan0xd7 . I agree you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jquery, use Jquery Dialogs. if you are using Jquery Mobile, use popups. Set the onclick method of your image-click to open the popup.
If using Jquery, you can use this code to generate a popup image to full screen (using a dialog).

For the link in your table:

```
<a href="#myPopupDialog" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="fade" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline">
<img border="0"  src="abc.jpg" width="100" height="100">
</a>
```

For the popup:

```
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <h2>Welcome to my Popup Dialog!</h2>
        <p>jQuery Mobile is FUN!</p>
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-left" data-rel="back">
 <img border="0"  src="abc.jpg" width="1000" height="1000">
</a>
      </div>
```

This should give you an idea.
Anyway there are heaps of examples online. Happy Googling!

Comment: PS: Didn't know about lightbox, looks like a much better option. Happy I learnsomething here everyday!